# Proving a certain transposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Trying to understand the proof of:

$A^T*A = (A^T*A)^T$

The solution was given
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGZYF.png)

I thought one would end with $A_{ik}*A_{jk}$, can anyone explain the fault in my reasoning?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(A^T*A)_{ij}=(A^T)_{ik} A_{kj}=A_{ki}A_{kj};\\
$$
$$
\left(\,(A^T*A)^T\right)_{ij}=(A^T*A)_{ji}=(A^T)_{jk}A_{ki}=A_{kj}A_{ki}
$$
equal to each other and to $ A_{ki}A_{kj}$.